# How can I enter 3 decimals behind the decimal point?

Tags: grails

I want to use g:field Tag in grails to enter a number with 3 decimals. If I enter 3 decimals grails rounds to second decimal by default. Third decimal is always lost. My suggestion is that I have to use the pattern="   " parameter of  Tag to force grails to store the 3rd decimal without rounding. But I don't know how the pattern should look like. I tried:

```
<g:field pattern="\\###,###.###" name="umlaufwert" value="${fieldValue(bean: itemInstance, field: 'umlaufwert')}"/>
```

But this won't work.

Is there any example ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the wrong question. Scaling with more than two decimals is not managed by tags. It is managed inside the domain class by setting:

```
static constraints = {
    ....
    feingehalt (nullable:true, scale:3)
}
```

and is propagated to database scheme from there.
Sorry for confusing some people.